# is $(1-e^{-x})^{-1}$ CDF function

Tags: probability-distributions

I have to prove that $(1-e^{-x})^{-1}$ is a cumulative distribution function. By properties of CDF's, 
the first one is $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1-e^{-x})^{-1}=0$.

When I re-write the $F_X(x)$ as $e^x/(e^x - 1)$
since $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^x =\infty$, I have $\infty/(\infty-1) =1$.

So the limit is $1$ (instead of $0$). Therefore this is not a CDF?
I'm just making sure I'm approaching this the right way.
Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Nofor a CDF the limit to $\infty$ is $1$, as this designifys the total probability, which is $1$. But you also have to check the limit to $-\infty$ this should be $0$.

Comment: Oops, I cannot handle that many minus signs!

Comment: Thank you, I just realized I made a mistake- the lim is of (minus infitnity), not infinity.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has a correct and obvious answer. There is nothing more to say.

Answer (score 1):

The given function $(1-e^{-x})^{-1} = \frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}$ is *not* a CDF because it is *decreasing* from $\infty$ at $x=0$ to $1$ as $x\to\infty$.

You claim that for all CDFs, $\lim_{x\to\infty} F_X(x) = 0$ and this property is *not* satisfied.  **Therefore** $(1-e^{-x})^{-1}$. In
actuality, the property you claim for all CDFs is incorrect (the limit is $1$, not $0$). Thus, while your *conclusion* that $(1-e^{-x})^{-1}$ is not
a valid CDF is correct, the *reason* that you state for your belief is
incorrect.

Even if you amend the purported CDF to be
$(1-e^{-x})^{-1}\mathbf 1_{\{x\colon x > 0\}}$, the function is
*not* a valid CDF because it is a *decreasing* function of $x$
on $(0,\infty)$.

Finally, please *don't* write thingies like
$\frac{\infty}{\infty-1}=1$.  Use the fact that 
$\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-x}=0$ to deduce that
$\lim_{x\to\infty}(1-e^{-x})^{-1} = 1$